# Is emplace_back ever better than push_back when adding temporary objects?

Tags: c++, vector, move, perfect-forwarding, emplace

Suppose we want to insert an object of type T into a container holding type T objects. Would emplace be better in any case? For example:

```
class MyClass {
    MyClass(int x) { ... }
}

MyClass CreateClass() {
    int x = ... // do long computation to get the value of x
    MyClass myClass(x);
    return myClass;
}

int main() {
    vector<MyClass> v;
    // I couldn't benchmark any performance differences between:
    v.push_back(CreateClass());
    // and
    v.emplace_back(CreateClass());
}
```

**Is there any argument to prefer** `v.emplace_back(CreateClass())` **rather than** `v.push_back(CreateClass())`?

Comment: What makes you think there is any difference betweem an object of type `T` and a string? A string is usually an object of type `std::string`, making the two equivalent.

Comment: @super But there is a difference between `std::string("a string")` and a string literal `"a string"`

Comment: @Enrico the comment at the end of the first answer does answer **my** question, thx.

Comment: Yes. And in relation to your question it is the same difference as `emplace_back(CreateClass())` and `emplace_back(10)`.

Comment: @super I deleted that fragment about strings. Is the question better-phrased now?

Comment: There is no difference btw emplace_back and push_back when object is already constructed, no matter it is temporary or not.

Comment: @Slava one question: would any compiler be allowed to do an optimisation of the following sort: "hey, I see `CreateClass() is a temporary that will never be used again, let me avoid creating a temporary and instead make the CreateClass method populate the last vector element with the data"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> suppose we want to insert an object of type T into a container holding type T objects. Would emplace be better in any case?

No; there would be no practical difference in that case.